# Shuffle array/mapping

Tags: solidity, arrays, mapping

Is it possible to shuffle the array or mapping of addresses? I tried this solution but it always returns the same result

```
 for (uint256 i = 0; i < arrayAddress.length; i++) {
            uint256 n = i + uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp))) % (arrayAddress.length - i);
            address temp = arrayAddress[n];
            arrayAddress[n] = arrayAddress[i];
            arrayAddress[i] = temp;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple solution for this. I used numbers instead of addresses to keep it simple and easy to visualize.

1. When using the `block.timestamp` and `block.number`, we need to be careful, since if the function (or the transaction) where you are using these values does not modify the state, then the `block.timestamp` and `block.number` will be the timestamp and block number of the last block that modified the state. Only when your function modifies the state that `block.timestamp` and `block.number` actually refer to different values. This may be the reason why you keep seeing the same results running your function multiple times, because `block.timestamp` is always the same (if you have not made any other transaction that modifies the state) and the `keccak256` function is creating the same hashes, thus the same results.
2. Maybe calculating a `keccak256` hash in every iteration of the `for` loop is not necessary. We could calculate a hash and then read each byte from it and use it as the value to create the index with the `%` operator that we need. Unless the length of our array is more than 256 elements, then we could read 2 bytes instead, which would provide us with about 65536 values, and so on.
   I suggest this because in case our array will never be more than 256 elements long, let's say that our array has 256 elements, we would only need to calculate the `keccak256` hash only about 256 / 32 times, which is 8 times, instead of the worse case 256 times, which is more efficient.
3. Modifying the state in a loop may not be a good idea and we could get an out of gas exception. To help with this, we can copy the state data as `memory`, modify it, then save it to storage again after the loop ends.
4. If you function does not modify state, then you cannot rely on the `block.timestamp` or `block.number`. Then you would need to somehow provide the 'seed' for your `keccak256` hash to be unique. Probably sending an extra parameter, a random number, etc., to your function so you use it instead of `block.timestamp`.

I wrote some code and put some comments and results below so you can see it, play with it and modify it:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.16;

// Autor: Jeremy Then

contract Shuffle {

    uint[] public uints = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

    function getInts() public view returns(uint[] memory) {
        return uints;
    }

    // This shuffle function works by creating a keccak256 hash of the current block.timestamp + a counter
    // to produce a different hash every time we need one.
    // Then, we use each byte as our value to generate the index we are going to swap the ith element with
    // by using the modulo (%) operator.
    // A keccak256 hash only has 32 bytes, so, in case the array we are trying to shuffle is bigger than
    // 32 elements, then we create a different keccak256 hash with the counter, and start taking each
    // byte of this new hash one by one to derive the index to swap the ith element with..
    // This function asumes that the array to shuffle is no bigger than 255 elements. If so,
    // then we would need to read 2 bytes instead of one. Because 1 byte only provides us 256 (2^8) values
    // to use as index, but 2 bytes would provide us with 65536 (2^16) values to use as index, which 
    // we then cut it down to the range of our array using the % operator.
    function shuffle() public returns(uint[] memory) {

        // Making a copy of the uints array, since modifying it from storage is really expensive
        // and we could get a out of gas exception
        uint[] memory uintsCopy = uints;

        uint counter = 0;
        uint j = 0;
        bytes32 b32 = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp + counter));
        uint length = uintsCopy.length;

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < uintsCopy.length; i++) {

            if(j > 31) {
                b32 = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp + ++counter));
                j = 0;
            }

            uint8 value = uint8(b32[j++]);

            uint256 n = value % length;

            uint temp = uintsCopy[n];
            uintsCopy[n] = uintsCopy[i];
            uintsCopy[i] = temp;
        }

        // Now, modifying the state uints array, once as a whole.
        uints = uintsCopy;

        return uintsCopy;
        
    }

    // Since this function does not modify the state and does not pay gas,
    // the `block.timestamp` will be the timestamp of the last block that modified the state
    // of this contract.
    // If another function is called that cause a state change, then that is an actual
    // transaction that was mined, paid gas and then block.timestamp will be the timestamp of the
    // block of that last transaction.
    function getTimestamp() public view returns(uint) {
        return block.timestamp;
    }

    // Since this function does not modify the state and does not pay gas,
    // the `block.number` will be the block number of the last block that modified the state
    // of this contract
    function getBlocknumber() public view returns(uint) {
        return block.number;
    }
    
}

// Running the shuffle function multiple times, it produced shuffled values like these:

// 15,12,5,2,19,10,16,1,3,11,20,9,7,13,8,6,18,4,17,14
// 11,1,4,9,16,3,17,10,14,19,2,6,13,8,7,15,12,5,18,20
// 7,1,17,6,16,18,20,2,15,5,10,11,3,13,14,12,19,8,9,4
// 18,4,1,6,11,14,10,20,7,2,3,5,13,12,16,8,15,19,17,9
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. This makes perfect sense. I will have to trigger this function only once when I deploy the second contract that pulls those shuffled values so this works for my use case.